# SVG Scrollbars needed on resizeable window inside flex layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, flexbox

When I want to see a small part of an SVG chart, with scrollbars to pan across it, I can do it like this:

```
<div style={{width: "800px", height: "500px", overflow: "scroll"} }>
 <svg className="gantt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      width="3000" height="450">
 </svg>
</div>
```

How do I get the same effect when the width of the outer div is not a fixed width?

```
<div style={{width: "90%", height: "500px", overflow: "scroll"} }>
```

*UPDATE*
I have found that the code above works fine except when placed inside `flex` layout. See below for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that the SVG was a child of a `flex` div which seems to cause problems with sizing. The solution I have found is to place the SVG in an absolutely positioned container.

```css
.svg {

  // actual size of svg...
  width: 3000px;
  height: 575px;


  // outer div to lock absolute position against...
  &__outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  // inner div for scrolling...
  &__container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 99%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```
<div className="svg__outer">
  <div className="svg__container">
    <svg className="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for me.

```html
<div style="width: 90%; height: 500px; overflow: scroll;">
 <svg className="gantt" 
      width="3000" height="450">
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that some CSS I have previous to this may be interfering, Will have to investigate. Might be flex related.